# Mailing labels with multiple relationships

Tags: custom-fields, export

Hoping for a little advice on the best way to address the following situation.

- We have individuals with relationships to organizations.  Each individual can have multiple relationships to organizations; each organization can have multiple relationships to individuals.
- Relationships have custom fields.
- Based on a query against the custom fields, the client wants to use tools (exports, mailing labels, etc.) which combine fields from both the individual and the organization.

A concrete example:

We want to generate a mailing to "delegates".  Each individual could be a delegate for many organizations, and each organization could have many delegates.  Whether or not an individual is a delegate is determined by a custom field in the relationship.

We need to generate an exports and mailing labels which include the name and phone number of the individual, and the name and address of the organization.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

```
        Sam
```

Comment: Hi - as per my forum feedback, can you provide an example of what the table would look like for John, Mary and Bob and Org X. Y and Z? Do you want a single row for John and 'all' his organisations as columns, or a row for each time he is a delegate, or grouped by Organisations, or by person, etc etc.

Comment: Alice, Bob, and Charlie are affiliated with organizations X-Ray, Yankee, and Zulu.  In particular: Alice is a delegate for X-Ray and Yankee; Bob is a delegate for Yankee and Zulu; Charlie is a delegate for Zulu only. 

We want to output five mailing labels, one for each relationship; each label would include the individual's name and phone number, as well as the organization's name and address, as well as fields from the relationship (role, etc.)

If the answer to this is just Drupal views ... I can figure it out from there.  Just wondering if there was an answer within Civi.

Comment: okay so a row per relationship. i would go Views. either based on Contact, or based on Relationships